# Akka Persistence - issue with Recovery - how to diagnose?

Tags: java, logging, akka, akka-persistence

I am using the java version of akka-persistence 2.3.4 where I have several actors which extend PersistentActor and which handle both RecoveryCompleted and RecoveryFailure. I am using the default journaling and snapshot plugins.

I'm running into this an issue with recovery where on some of my actors I get neither a RecoveryCompleted nor RecoveryFailure message and the actor gets stuck.

What kind of diagnostics can I use to figure out why this may be happening?

I have tried turning on debug logging but no akka logging shows up there.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm interested in this question too